# How to use microcaching

Tags: caching

I found this link on microcaching and speeding up websites but to be honest I don't understand it. Can someone explain where exactly the code within it goes

http://fennb.com/microcaching-speed-your-app-up-250x-with-no-n

Answer (score 1):

Before you consider any sort of performance optimizations for your site, you need to first understand where the slow parts are. Otherwise, you will be optimizing pieces that do not need optimizing. This technique is called "performance profiling."

Additionally, I would encourage you to read general-purpose articles on reverse proxies and caching. Read about Varnish; APC; memcached. This will give you some high-level understanding of the problem space. Only then should you go and implement something.

Comment: Thanks for that, it makes sense to understand where the lag is occurring before looking at what to fix. Memcached is something I definitely will be looking at.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's all about setting up a proxy that caches your websites. The code there is example configuration for nginx, a web server known for its outstanding speed.